# Json response is wrong. (DataTable)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I wouldn't ask, but I really need.

Well, I'm trying to update my DataTable with ajax. One of my tables is ok, but the other isn't.

Here's the code.
The First one is the PHP that the user will acess. And the second is the AJAX url.

p.s: My arrays names are in Portuguese, sorry about that.

**clientes.php**

```
  <?php
// Aqui será chamado o BD e conexões necessárias.
require_once("db.php");

try {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM telesena.clientes;";
  $resultado = $con->query($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e){
  echo "Estamos passando por um problema. Tente novamente mais tarde.";
}
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>

<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.13/b-1.2.4/b-html5-1.2.4/sc-1.4.2/datatables.min.css"/>
<!-- Scripts necessários para DataTable e jQuery -->

<title> Pedidos Tele-Sena </title>

<!-- Chamando o Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">


<body>
  <!-- Nav principal -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <a class="navbar-brand"> Logo da Empresa </a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Clientes</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!-- Começando a fazer a tabela de clientes -->
  <div class="container">
    <table id="clientes" class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Cód. Convênio</th>
          <th>Nome Fantasia</th>
          <th>Razão Social</th>
          <th>Logradouro</th>
          <th>Número</th>
          <th>Bairro</th>
          <th>Município</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>UF</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.13/b-1.2.4/b-html5-1.2.4/sc-1.4.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.toaster.js"></script>

</body>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clientes').DataTable({
    "serverSide":true,
    "oProcessing":true,
    "ajax":"ajaxclientes.php",
    "processing":true,
    "bSort":false,
    "bPaginate":false,
    "language":{
    "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ".",
    "sLengthMenu": "Clientes por página: _MENU_ ",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
    "sProcessing": "Processando...",
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sSearch": "Pesquisar ",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sNext": "Próximo",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior",
        "sFirst": "Primeiro",
        "sLast": "Último"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma crescente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<!-- Modal padrão e todos os scripts necessários estão sendo chamados do info.php-->

</html>
```

**ajaxclientes.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once("db.php");

$start  = $_GET['start'];
$length = $_GET['length'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER BY Cod_Convenio ASC;";
$resultado = $con->query($sql);
$resposta = array();
$resposta['recordsTotal'] = $length;

if (!$resultado) {
    $resposta = array(
        'status' => false,
        'message' => 'Houve um pequeno problema...'
    );
} else {
    $resposta = array(
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'Tudo ocorreu bem',
        'data' => $resultado ->fetchAll()
    );
}

//print_r($resposta);
echo json_encode($resposta);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any update code. Also what do you mean "One of my tables is ok, but the other isn't."?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? you don't see the data get draw on the clients.php? You don't seem to have the callback function from the Datatable that draw the table.

Comment: "DataTable warning: table clientes= id invalide Json Response. " it's what i'am receiving

Comment: "One of my tables is ok, but the other isn't." -- I have other table in another page that is exactly like this one, but working correctly.

Comment: OK. I saw what was my problem. I had to force utf8 encode in my array before encode with json. Now it's working fine.